# Safari can't connect to localhost - Java OAth

Tags: network, safari, java

I am trying to write a Java code and I'm trying to do OAuth. I created an authentication URL which I'm supposed to go to with Safari with a callback url set as http://LocalHost except Safari said can't open page because Safari can't connect to server LocalHost

I've been all of the pages in AskDifferent and tried all the solutions like clearing cache, unchecking all of the proxies in System Preferences, deleting HSTS.plist and etc
The weirdest part is that when I go into the search bar for https://localhost it actually takes me to a page saying "It Works"

How do I fix this?

Comment: If your callback URL is `http://LocalHost`, but you can go to `https://localhost`, why not try changing the callback URL to `https://localhost`? Can't speak directly for Java, but know some languages are case sensitive.

Comment: And just to be sure you know that macOS will use a web root folder in your user folder *by default* rather than the one in the system root location?

Comment: @karolus oh my callback was lowercase whoops

Comment: @SteveChambers im not really sure what that is

Comment: As i recall "/Users/[USERNAME]/Sites/" is set as the default HTTP document root and /Library/Webserver/Documents *USED* to be the default. You will have to view/edit the HTTP/Apache configuration file to see what it is using. It's been a LONG time since I did any web work on macOS so I'm going by vaguely remembered details...

Comment: The default folder on MacOS is indeed `/users/[Username]/Sites`, for the project root. As far as a running application, that will depend upon your local development setup. Is there a configuration file within your codebase where this is specified? For instance, for Linux stacks on a VM, would be something like `/var/www/[Project Name]/[Designated Folder]`